# python 3 - how to split a key in a dictionary in 2

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary, cs50

This is my first post, so if I miss something, let me know.

I'm doing a CS50 beginner python course, and I'm stuck with a problem.

Long story short, the problem is to open a csv file, and it looks like this:

name,house

"Abbott, Hannah",Hufflepuff

"Bell, Katie",Gryffindor
.....

So I would love to put into a dictionary (which I did), but the problem now is that I supposed to split the "key" name in 2.

Here is my code, but it doesn't work:

before = []

....

```
    with open(sys.argv[1]) as file:

        reader = csv.reader(file)
        for name, house in reader:
            before.append({"name": name, "house": house})

        # here i would love to split the key "name" in "last", "first"

        for row in before[1:]:
            last, first = name.split(", ")
```

Any advice?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After you have the dictionary with complete name, you can split the name as below:

```
before = [{"name": "Abbott, Hannah", "house": "Hufflepuff"}]

# Before split
print(before)

for item in before:
    # Go through each item in before dict and split the name
    last, first = item["name"].split(', ')

    # Add new keys for last and first name
    item["last"] = last
    item["first"] = first

    # Remove the full name entry
    item.pop("name")

# After split
print(before)
```

You can also do the split from the first pass, e.g. store directly the last and first instead of full name.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I've copied and pasted your code but the result is :

last, first = item["name"].split(', ')

ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)

Any ideas?

Comment: Are all the names a comma separated string, in the format "last, first"? e.g : "Abbott, Hannah"

Comment: yes, but the first line is just name, house with no quotes

Comment: It would be helpful if you can provide how `before` dictionary looks. Just do a `print(before)` outside the for loop, just above the comment line. You can go around the value error by using a try/except block around `last, first = item["name"].split(', ')`. In case value error is triggered, just put `pass` in the `except ValueError:` block

Comment: the "before.csv" was partially in the beginning of the post.
and thanks to your help, and changing a little bit your code everything works. Thank you so much for your help!